# `unique` in data.frame.describe() not work [python][pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, unique, describe

Hi it's something fundamental but I can't fix it... `unique()` shows unique values in each column, but `describe()` shows NaN. Why... Any help's appreciated. thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0)

# works:
train['Pclass'].unique()
# array([3, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
train['Survived'].unique()
# array([0, 1], dtype=int64)

# not work:
train.describe(include='all')
#         PassengerId    Survived      Pclass               Name   Sex  \
# count    891.000000  891.000000  891.000000                891   891   
# unique          NaN         NaN         NaN                891     2   
# top             NaN         NaN         NaN  Mitkoff, Mr. Mito  male   
# freq            NaN         NaN         NaN                  1   577   
# mean     446.000000    0.383838    2.308642                NaN   NaN   
# std      257.353842    0.486592    0.836071                NaN   NaN   
# min        1.000000    0.000000    1.000000                NaN   NaN   
# 25%      223.500000    0.000000    2.000000                NaN   NaN   
# 50%      446.000000    0.000000    3.000000                NaN   NaN   
# 75%      668.500000    1.000000    3.000000                NaN   NaN   
# max      891.000000    1.000000    3.000000                NaN   NaN   
# 
#                Age       SibSp       Parch  Ticket        Fare        Cabin  \
# count   714.000000  891.000000  891.000000     891  891.000000          204   
# unique         NaN         NaN         NaN     681         NaN          147   
# top            NaN         NaN         NaN  347082         NaN  C23 C25 C27   
# freq           NaN         NaN         NaN       7         NaN            4   
# mean     29.699118    0.523008    0.381594     NaN   32.204208          NaN   
# std      14.526497    1.102743    0.806057     NaN   49.693429          NaN   
# min       0.420000    0.000000    0.000000     NaN    0.000000          NaN   
# 25%      20.125000    0.000000    0.000000     NaN    7.910400          NaN   
# 50%      28.000000    0.000000    0.000000     NaN   14.454200          NaN   
# 75%      38.000000    1.000000    0.000000     NaN   31.000000          NaN   
# max      80.000000    8.000000    6.000000     NaN  512.329200          NaN   
# 
#        Embarked  
# count       889  
# unique        3  
# top           S  
# freq        644  
# mean        NaN  
# std         NaN  
# min         NaN  
# 25%         NaN  
# 50%         NaN  
# 75%         NaN  
# max         NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `describe` method for numeric columns doesn't list the number of unique values, since this is usually not particularly meaningful for numeric data, the `describe` method for string columns does:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'string_column': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'numeric': [1, 2, 1]})

df['numeric'].describe()
Out[6]: 
count    3.000000
mean     1.333333
std      0.577350
min      1.000000
25%      1.000000
50%      1.000000
75%      1.500000
max      2.000000
Name: numeric, dtype: float64

df['string_column'].describe()
Out[7]: 
count     3
unique    2
top       a
freq      2
Name: string_column, dtype: object
```

Since your dataframe contains both, the results are being merged and `nan`s inserted where the column doesn't have that value.

If your numeric columns are actually just codes reflecting different classes/categories, you might want to convert them to `Categorical` to get more meaningful info about them:

```
df['categorized'] = pd.Categorical(df['numeric'])

df['categorized'].describe()
Out[10]: 
count     3
unique    2
top       1
freq      2
Name: categorized, dtype: int64
```

Comment: v helpful on the numeric vs string and use of `pd.Categorical`